# How to get a work permit in Shanghai, China after being exchange student for 4 months?

Tags: working-visas, students, china, hong-kong, taiwan

I was an exchange student at Duke Kunshan University, Kunshan, China and graduated this June. I heard the Chinese government has recently revised visa laws to offer work permits to all students who graduate from a program in China, but doesn't say what kinds of programs are eligible for this.

I'm also open to working in HK and Taiwan.

Does anyone have any information about this?

Comment: Currently you're asking about more than one country, which is generally too broad for here. It's best to ask sobjective questions with just one possible answer, on one topic - in order to best get answers on expats.SE. Please see the [help].